# In VBA how do I restore keyboard shortcut to default?

Tags: vba, keyboard-shortcuts

In my VBA Excel add-in, I allow the user to assign arbitrary keyboard shortcuts to my public macros. I allow them to change these shortcuts at runtime *(really, they change a configuration file and then reload it)*. I use `Application.OnKey` to do this.

If the user changes a shortcut at runtime, how can I restore any previous default definition for the old keyboard shortcut?

For example, if I have programmatically assigned `^S` to a macro, and then change it to `^E`, how can I restore `^S` to the original Excel "Save" behavior?

Comment: I should mention, for backward-compatibility reasons, I need to be able to support some shortcuts that override default behavior; I must at least allow the option of ^S, ^D, and ^B which I know all have default behaviors.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To return a key defined through `OnKey` to its default, define it with no procedure.

This sets <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> to "SpecialPrintProc"

```
Application.OnKey "^S", "SpecialPrintProc"
```

This returns <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> to its normal meaning.

```
Application.OnKey "^S"
```

This disables <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>.

```
Application.OnKey "^S", ""
```

Comment: Is there a way to reset *all* keys at once?

Comment: I don't see any method to do that, apart from quitting excel entirely (closing the workbook itself would not work, as if excel is still running, it will remember the assignments).

Comment: I guess I will have to limit the user's options, and go through my list on Auto_Close to reset them to defaults, then.